# Sending POST data via javascript to a PHP safely

Tags: ajax, json, twitter, http-post

I'm trying to work around the fact that twitter uses a call-limit by letting the client do a call to Twitter(By parameters given by my script, like last_id, username etc) and give me the newly found tweets by posting them via an AJAX request that I store in my database after.

However, if i figure out the parameters that are being sent from my getTweets javascript function to my save_tweets.php via a JSON array it's not that hard to post random stuff with an extension like the REST console in chrome.

Obviously i want the tweets to be legit and can not be manipulated(or posted) by anyone. I understand that javascript is clientside and therefore there is not much control over the content being grabbed and put away again but is there a way to be safe that the POST data you send comes from a user/webpage that is allowed to do so?

I've tried thinking of a PHP session token or something, but that doesn't fly since you have to cross-check that token which you therefore have to send along with the JSON array to my PHP.

Thanks in advance,

p.s If you know a different way to not being obstructed by a call limit to Twitter i'd be happy with that too. But 150 calls from a server isn't that much if you get a 1000+ users an hour to your page.